# Error userRateLimitExceeded

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I'm trying to make an app that would automatically share documents for our team.
I use the API method "drive.permissions.insert". All good, but after a while I start getting errors:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   { 
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "userRateLimitExceeded",
    "message": "Rate limit exceeded. User message: \"Квота совместного доступа превышена.\""
   }
   ],
   "code": 403,
   "message": "Rate limit exceeded. User message: \"Квота совместного доступа превышена.\""
  }
}
```

My request exapmle:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B_7sOpJvz1WpZnczelg2aXRXYjA/permissions?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.4gABrB78psFgf0uFQJMSGOkC8rSnw7ckN2kX9rwCAou3lGM-JD4GZvGCHukAjWvQop9g55iPzkE7Yw
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "role": "writer",
 "type": "user",
 "value": "user@gmail.com"
}
```

I understand that I have come across some inherent API limitations.

What do I do to get around these limitations?

Will help the connection paid API billing?

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the question. "Rate limit exceeded." means you are submitting requests to Drive too quickly.

Drive can handle a burst of (approx) 20 update transactions well, but after that it throttles transactions to a rate of approx 1 per 2 seconds. This limit cannot be changed.

Comment: Limits are not exceeded. I send no more requests per second.  
The problem comes after several dozen calls drive.permissions.insert.  
Feels like my application block for 24 hours, then everything works fine, but after a few dozen calls again, I ran across a API blocking.

Comment: check the settings at https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect#project:xxxxxxxxxxxxx:quotas where xxxx is your numeric project ID. afair the default is 10m per day, so it's not likely that is your problem, but worth checking.

Comment: also try increasing the per user rate per second which defaults to 10

Comment: My quota is not exceeded.
It is 100%.
Tried to increase the value per user rate per second, it is not all the same does not help.
What else to try?

Comment: "Квота совместного доступа превышена" for english mean "You have exceeded your sharing quota". 
I think it has something to do with the problem described [https://support.google.com/drive/troubleshooter/2525254?hl=en#ts=2525295](https://support.google.com/drive/troubleshooter/2525254?hl=en#ts=2525295)
Here I recommend to wait 24 hours. My application requests "drive.permissions.insert" start successfully performed the next day. I counted, I got about 70 successful requests, then my app blocked for 24 hours again.

Comment: @pinoyyid what is the purpose of the `Per-user limit` in the API console then if it simply throttles down to approx 1 per 2 seconds?

Comment: URL is now: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/quotas?project=project-xxxxxxxxxxxxx&authuser=0

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs to implement [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors) rather than trying to space requests out on your own. Send them in succession until you get a rate limited exceeded error, then backoff and retry until you get a successful call again.

Comment: Read my previous comments.
Exponential backoff needed if the requests are sending too often.
My application is sent 70 requests, after which it is blocked for 24 hours.
I need help with some of Google's engineers, who were able to see what is really happening with my application.
My Project ID: rapid-arbor-522 Project Number: 462887361833

Comment: My point was that you should implement exponential backoff no matter what, even when doing only one call. The docs state that if you don't respond appropriately to backoff requests, you may see your app blocked for longer periods.

Comment: My application is not blocked. All requests are successful. The only problem with "drive.permissions.insert".